# Eclipse showing arg0, arg1 although JDK1.7 was installed and selected

Tags: java, eclipse

Having read several of the previous posts on this topic, I have the following situation :

Eclipse - Window - Preferences - Installed JRE's points to C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0.60 Standard VM.

Yet when 'adding unimplemented methods', it adds functions with parameters named arg0, arg1 etc.

I increased the suggested timeout value, but no change.
Javadoc location is set to c:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_60/bin/

What else do I need to correct ?

Please advise.
Thanks
A

Comment: What does JDK have to do with eclipse auto generate methods feature? And what is __wrong__ with arg0, arg1, you can change them.

Comment: For me, it would be easier to get some semantics (view, position, etc) instead of listed arguments (arg0, arg1,..). Hence I am asking.

Comment: Is the Interface you're implementing part of the JDK? Does the project you're in target that JDK? Can you open its source from within Eclipse of see its doc in the JavaDoc View?

Comment: When clicking on a method (e.g. setContentView), JavaDoc shows a description. When adding unimplemented methods, JavaDoc doesn't show a description. Do I need to run Project-Generate Javadocs ?

Answer (score 0):

The sources are probably not associated with the runtime libraries.

- Navigate to [Installed JREs](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp) in the preferences
- Select your JDK and click *Edit...*
- Expand each jar and use the *Source Attachment...* button to associate it with src.zip

You can find src.zip in your JDK directory.

*Kepler assumed.*

Comment: Still not there. I am trying to implement OnItemSelectedListener. With Eclipse I am getting :  onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3).  With IntelliJ I get onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l).

Comment: With McDowell's comments : I have installed JDK : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45 and JRE C:\Program Files\Java\jre7. Under Installed JREs I have selected the JDK. I followed McDowell's comments and edited in the JDK each Source attachment to C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/src.zip. What else to do, to get Eclipse like IntelliJ ?

Comment: `OnItemSelectedListener` is not in the JDK library; use the _Navigate > Open Type..._ (CTRL+ALT+T) menu to locate open the type and use the _Link with Editor_ button in the _Project Explorer_ view to locate the JAR. You can then set the source and documentation locations (assuming you have them.)